# what vulnerability does 'pypasser' exploit?

Tags: captcha

The project [pypasser](https://github.com/xHossein/PyPasser) claims to bypass "[vulnerable](https://github.com/xHossein/PyPasser#exception)" reCaptcha v3 [sites](https://github.com/xHossein/PyPasser/blob/master/pypasser/sites.json). What vulnerability?

Comment: You are essentially asking us to review someone's code, parse all the logic flow, and to provide you with the documentation that the developer didn't provide. Unfortunately, we are not a code review or analysis site. You should contact the developer. Issue a bug and request better documentation.

Comment: I narrowed the question's focus by removing my research, but a respondent will still probably have to read some code to determine which vulnerability pypasser uses. Or maybe it is common knowledge?

Comment: So, now, we have to parse the whole code base, try to determine how it works, then try to understand what vulnerability applies? This is actually worse than the original question. I think you just need to ask the developer.

Comment: Instead of spending time asking *here*, spend even less time and post on the issue tracker ...